# Anyone have luck running virtualenv within AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda only support python2.7. While searching on WWW for how to run pythong3, I stumbled up on http://cloudtrek.com.au/blog/running-python-3-on-aws-lambda/

After following instructions from above article, I noticed that I am not able to run anything within my virtualenv/bin/ directory.

I wrote a handler function that will use subprocess module to invoke python3 stored within my virtualenv. But that handler function is returning 'File not Found" error. I am made sure that virtualenv/bin directory has python and other executables. Even I tried to run pip stored within virtualenv/bin but that is also returning same error. If I pass handler function 'ls -al' argument, it lists that virtualenv/bin has all the binaries inside it.

Did anyone have success invoking virtualenv/bin or python3 withing AWS Lambda?

Comment: I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520389/run-python3-without-activating-the-virtual-environment

Comment: a python3.6 runtime is now available https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/5198208415517126