# Run Python3 without activating the virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, aws-lambda

My objective is to run Python 3 code on the AWS Lambda Service, which currently only supports Python 2.7. These are the steps I have done.

- Since I work on a Mac, setup a docker image [similar](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) to the AWS Lambda Linux instance.
- [Build](http://www.diveintopython.net/installing_python/source.html) Python3 from source on the docker image.
- In the docker image create a virtual environment and copy it to my project.
- AWS Lambda requires you to create a zip of the code and upload it to their service. For this prototype, I have a zip with three artifacts at the root

  1. `handler.py`: This is a Python 2.7 file. The `handler` function in this file will be executed by the AWS Lambda Service when an event occurs (e.g. When a new file is created in a S3 bucket).

     ```
     def handler(event, context):
         execution_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
         commands = '''
         source venv/bin/activate && venv/bin/python3.6 ./handler_python3.py --execution_uuid {ex_uuid}
         '''.format(ex_uuid=str(execution_uuid))
         p = Popen('/bin/bash', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
         stdout, stderr = p.communicate(commands)
         pprint(stdout)
         pprint(stderr)
     ```
  2. `handler_python3.py`. This is the Python3 file called by the earlier `handler.py` file. Note the `execution_uuid` being read. I have taken out the code that uses it for brevity but I do need it and I am using `argparse` to extract it.

     ```
     def read_execution_uuid():
         import argparse
         parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
         parser.add_argument("--execution_uuid", required=True)
         args = parser.parse_args()

         return args.execution_uuid

     def handler(event, context):
         import sys
         print(sys.path)

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         execution_uuid = read_execution_uuid()
         handler(event, context)
     ```

     3. `venv` folder. This is the virtual environment folder that I copied from the docker image.

When I run the AWS Lambda Service, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./handler_python3.py", line 38, in <module>
    execution_uuid = read_execution_uuid()
  File "./handler_python3.py", line 7, in read_execution_uuid
    import argparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'argparse\'
```

Notes:

- If I remove the `argparse` code and the `handler` function in `handler_python3.py` executes, it shows the following values for `sys.path`

  ```
  ['/var/task', '/var/runtime', '/var/task/venv/lib/python36.zip', '/var/task/venv/lib/python3.6', '/var/task/venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/var/task/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
  ```

Notes:

- I can install argparse explicitly. But I'd like not to.
- Note the `source venv/bin/activate` command in the python 2.7 file `handler.py`. That doesn't work on the Lambda instance though it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual environment does not copy all the modules from the `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` directory. I had to copy all the files there.